# Postgres increment SERIAL column per transaction

Tags: postgresql

If I understand `SERIAL` type correctly, it is auto-incremented if no value is specified for every `INSERT` statement. I was wondering if I can have auto-increment applied once per group of `INSERT`s or even per transactions.

E.g. If I do 3 inserts committing after each one I get `1,2,3` in the `SERIAL` column. I wanted to create single transaction that has 3 inserts and increment the row affected rows, ending up with `1,1,1` in the `SERIAL` column for those rows. If I were to do this again, I would get `2,2,2` not `4,5,6`

Comment: Not possible with a serial column. You could create a "regular" sequence, and then query the sequence for `nextval()` at the start of your transaction and then use `currval()` in all inserts during that transaction.

Comment: Argh, I suspected as much, but thanks for confirming this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sequence as described by @a_horse_with_no_name and automate the process with a function that provides the default value. The same value will be returned when called multiple times in a transaction.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_id_seq;

CREATE FUNCTION test_id_nextval() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
    retval INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Try to fetch the current value.
    SELECT * FROM test_id_seq_temp LIMIT 1 INTO STRICT retval;
    RETURN retval;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN undefined_table THEN
        -- The function hadn't been called yet during this transaction.
        -- Create a temporary table for the next value of the sequence and return it.
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_id_seq_temp ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT nextval('test_id_seq');
        SELECT * FROM test_id_seq_temp LIMIT 1 INTO STRICT retval;
        RETURN retval;
END;
$$ VOLATILE LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER DEFAULT test_id_nextval());
```